# Connect to HDFS location from Azure databricks notebook to get the file number and size

Tags: scala, hadoop, hdfs, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to connect to hdfs location from databricks notebook to get the file details.

below are the code which I tried to obtain the same

```
%fs ls dbfs:/mnt/<mount>/dev/data/audit/
```

And i obtained result with size as 0. And only the details of folder audit, not any of its subfolders.
[image]

audit folder is having 5 more subfolders with files inside that. I want to get number of files in each subfolders and total size of those 5 subfolders.

I tried below **dbutils** in scala, but it doesnt have any function to get number of files or size of a file.

1. Is there any way to get the size of folders and sub folders in hdfs from databricks notebook?
2. Is there any way to get number of files in folders and sub folders in hdfs from databricks notebook?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple method in `dbutils` that returns size of directory or number of files in a directory. However you can do calculation iterating directories recursively.

**1. Number of files recursive calculation:**

```scala
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.FileInfo
import com.databricks.dbutils_v1

private lazy val dbutils = dbutils_v1.DBUtilsHolder.dbutils

def numberOfFiles(location: String): Int = {
  @tailrec
  def go(items: List[FileInfo], result: Int): Int = items match {
    case head :: tail =>
      val files = dbutils.fs.ls(head.path)
      val directories = files.filter(_.isDir)
      go(tail ++ directories, result + files.size)
    case _ => result
  }

  go(dbutils.fs.ls(location).toList, 0)
}
```

**2. Total size of a folder**

```scala
import com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.FileInfo

def sizeOfDirectory(location: String): Long = {
  @tailrec
  def go(items: List[FileInfo], result: Long): Long = items match {
    case head :: tail =>
      val files = dbutils.fs.ls(head.path)
      val directories = files.filter(_.isDir)
      val updated = files.map(_.size).foldLeft(result)(_ + _)
      go(tail ++ directories, updated)
    case _ => result
  }

  go(dbutils.fs.ls(location).toList, 0)
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I tried running this code in notebook by providing the location but i am getting the below error.
```command-642381869458415:23: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Int
}
^```
And if i change the type to Any I am getting below error.
```loc: String = /mnt/mount/dev/audit/
numberOfFiles: (location: String)Any```@bob

Comment: @Antony can you try something like this: `abfss://FILESYSTEM@ACCOUNTNAME.dfs.core.windows.net/`

Comment: I have added the screenshot in the question. Please check and let me know if calling method or anything is wrong. I am new to scala and databricks.

Comment: @Antony try like this: `val loc = "dbfs:/mnt/mount/dev/audit/"`